# Function headers in c

Tags: c, return

Say I have the following function:

```
void *mycalloc(size_t num, size_t size, char *file, unsigned int line){
    char *retptr = mymalloc((num * size), file, line); 
    if(!retptr){
        return NULL;
    }
    else{
        header *blk_header = (header *)retptr - 1;
        for(int i=0; i<blk_header->size; i++){
            retptr[i] = 0;
        }
        return retptr; //<-- at this point
    }
}
```

Function header says that function will return a **void ***, however my pointer is a **char *** so that I can set every byte to 0x00, as is required for calloc. Would it be redundant to cast **retptr** to a **void *** on return or does the function header determine the type returned? I guess what I'm asking is: Would this cause a problem for the caller that expects a **void *** returned?

Comment: Yes, it would be redundant, since `void *` is implicitly convertible to and from any non-qualified object pointer type. It would decrease readability as well, so **it would actually be harmful.** Also, [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

Comment: You might consider using `memset` instead to zero out the memory.  It's more likely to be optimized, and you don't have to worry about different pointer types.

Comment: a `void*` in C will be implicitly converted to any pointer type when appropriate.  This is why you don't cast the return value of `malloc`

Comment: @cHao that's really interesting, never heard about it

Comment: @EdS. nitpick: any *object* pointer type. (it needn't work with function pointers.)

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: As far as I am aware that has nothing to do with the conversion from `void*` to `some_other_pointer_type` and everything to do with converting a function pointer to a function pointer of a different type *and then calling the function via the pointer*, which results in UB.  The cast/conversion has nothing to do with it; it's the function call that causes a problem.

Comment: @EdS. it seems I'm talking about a different problem. You stated that `void *` can be converted to any pointer type, which is not the case because there may be no conversion between `void *` and a function pointer type (in either direction). I'm not talking about function return types anymore.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: Wow, I had to look that one up.  After ~10 years of using C I didn't know that.  Good thing I never felt the need to attempt it...

Comment: @EdS. :) We always learn something new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would it be redundant to cast retptr to a void * on return or does the function header determine the type returned?

Yes it would. The conversion will take place automatically.

---

To get a clearer view on this topic, you might consider this example, which uses numerical data for intuitive reasons:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int get_pi() {
  double pi = 3.14;
  return pi;
}


int main(void) {

  double pi = get_pi();
  printf("%f\n", pi);

  return 0;
}
```

This will print 3.000. What happened?

Inside the function we initialized the `double` variable as we should and we then returned it. Automatically the variable got the type of the return type of `foo()`, which is `int`.

That means that the `double` will be converted to `int`, thus 3.14 to 3. Then we assign the return value of the function to a double variable, but the decimal digits are lost, as you can see in the `printf()`.

---

As suggested by cHao:

"You might consider using memset instead to zero out the memory. It's more likely to be optimized, and you don't have to worry about different pointer types."

> void * memset ( void * ptr, int value, size_t num );
>
> Fill block of memory
>
> Sets the first num bytes of the block of memory pointed by ptr to the specified value (interpreted as an unsigned char).

Take a look at the example to see how `memset()` is used

```
/* memset example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] = "almost every programmer should know memset!";
  memset (str,'-',6);
  puts (str);
  return 0;
}
```

The example comes from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/), where you can find the reference too.

Comment: Thanks for the example, it really did make it easier to reason it out

Comment: You are welcome. Moreover the example shows that the cast will take place no matter what, regardless of it is what we intended or not (in the example we would like to have 3.14 returned, but the automatic conversion make this not to happen). Also, I will update my answer with `memset`, as suggested in the comments, since I agree. @MauricioTrajano

Answer (score 1):

The cast will be from a more "specific" type (`char*`) to a more "generic" one (`void *`).
It's much like returning an `int` from a function that returns `double`. An implicit cast is made that doesn't affect the caller.

However if a `char *` is the only data type that your function needs to return then set the return type to `char *`

Comment: `s/implicit cast/implicit conversion/g`. A "cast" is explicit by definition. And this doesn't answer the question.